# Best practice of deleting draft properties using Immer with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, immer.js

I want to edit original object data without mutation and possibly without deep cloning the original object. I found [Immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer). Using its `produce` function works just fine. But when I want to [delete](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/update-patterns#object-mutations) original object property I get an error `The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.` which is understandable.

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  age: number;
}

const user: User = {
  name: 'John',
  surname: 'Small',
  age: 20
}

const changedUser = produce(user, (draft) => {
  draft.name = 'Mark';
  delete draft.age; // The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.
})
```

I can force its `Base` type like `produce<Partial<User>>(/* ... */)` but I think it's ugly and if you would like to edit nested objects, you would have to sanitize possible undefined errors. Are there any more suitable approaches?

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about where you are using your `User` and whether that usage is expecting to always have a complete `User` object.  When you delete `age` from the `user` variable, changedUser is, by definition, not a `User`.  So if you need a `User` then you should not do this.

If your code is ok with having an incomplete `User` object, then in my opinion you should be declaring that higher-up rather than on the `produce` function.  When you create "John", make the type `const user: Partial<User> = ...`.

I imagine that your actual code is more complex than this.  So the place to introduce the `Partial` type is in the type definition for whatever `state` object you are altering with the `produce`.

With regards to making nested properties optional, you can use a [utility type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132262/typescript-deep-partial) for that.