# How does this DeepPartial type work from Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I was looking through this question here:

[TypeScript: deep partial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132262/typescript-deep-partial)

The top answer has DeepPartial type defined as follows:

```
type DeepPartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[P]>;
};
```

I tested and this type works as expected, but I can't fully understand how this works internally.

let's take example interface from the same question:

```
interface Foobar {
  foo: number;
  bar: {
    baz: boolean;
    qux: string;
  };
}
```

when P=bar, it's easy to understand that recursively it will go into

```
DeepPartial<{
    baz: boolean;
    qux: string;
  }>
```

and make "baz" and "qux" keys optional.

But what I don't get is how does the recursion work for primitive types?
Like for `foo` key, how is `DeepPartial<number>` same as `number`? When T=number,

```
[P in keyof number]?: DeepPartial<number[P]>;
```

doesn't make sense to me.

In my mind, the implementation of DeepPartial should be something like:

```
type DeepPartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: isPrimitive(T[P]) ? T[P] : DeepPartial<T[P]>;
};
```

But original implementation works also, and I don't get how.

I hope I explained my question well enough. Here is example playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0CM5WQbwChlkZMAuZEAVwFstoBuY5HKSokknAL0q0wAbCHBDMuyAI7UAHpQDOYKKADm45AF9mGwoTABPAA4oAIhAiGACrjDA4ggDwAVAHzIAvARYkA2peSgyADWEProMMhOALoA-JRmFtZQtvbOflEu2syECOggiqSYbPHmVjZ2jhjYuG6enIXolACMADQsxQSscHzIStQoOlq6uflgvRCKAJLgJYnlqTT00LXIAKzMQA

**Edit:**
I investigated further and found out that

```
type DeepPartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: any;
};

type DeepPartialTest<T> = {
        [P in keyof number]?: any;
    };
```

now `DeepPartial<number>` will return **number** type, but `DeepPartialTest<number>` will not. Which makes this even weirder for me.

**Edit 2 add screenshots:**

This works as expected:

[image]

This doesn't:

[image]

When in reality both should be the same??

Comment: `DeepPartial` just makes the keys optional. `number` is a primitie and doesn't technically have keys, so `DeepPartial<number>` is a no-op

Comment: but shouldn't DeepPartial<number> return empty object ({}) type in that case and not "number" type?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. A primitive technically doesn't have methods, it's just converted to an object when you use any methods on it. You cannot claim to have a number (e.g., `42`) but you somehow cannot do `(42).toString()` because you cannot remove `toString()` from primitives. They are immutable.

Comment: Still don't get how DeepPartial<number> returns number type. So if I define DeepPartial<T> type as object with no keys (since keyof number doesn't have keys), I get just T as a result instead of object with no keys? Can't grasp how the logic works

Comment: `number` is a primitive, not an object. Primitives are immutable, so it doesn't make sense to have different properties on `5` and `42`.

Comment: ok, so to clarify, if I did:

type DeepPartial<T> = {
    
};

then DeepPartial<number> is empty object;

But if I did 

type DeepPartial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: any;
};

then for DeepPartial<number> typescript would just return "number" back, because we are doing no-op inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually an internal mechanism in TypeScript for type parameters which states that:

> when a primitive type is substituted for T in an isomorphic mapped
> type, we simply produce that primitive type.

You can read more about it in this [pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12447).

Answer (score 3):

I think the question is "why do mapped types acting on primitives produce those same primitives and why does it only seem to happen sometimes" and not about `DeepPartial` per se, right?

---

[Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) come in two "flavors".  There are normal mapped types which just iterate over some arbitrary union of property key literals (e.g., `{[P in K]: ...}`), and *homomorphic* mapped types which iterate specifically over the keys of another type (e.g., `{[P in keyof T]: ...}`), and try to *preserve the structure* of that type by, say, copying modifiers like `readonly` and `?` from the input type to the output type (unless you change the modifiers with your own `readonly` or `?` and `+` or `-`).  Example:

```
interface Obj {
  a?: number,
  b: string,
  readonly c: boolean
}

type Homomorphic<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Array<T[K]>
}
type ObjHom = Homomorphic<Obj>
/* type ObjHom = {
    a?: (number | undefined)[] | undefined;
    b: string[];
    readonly c: boolean[];
} */

type ObjKeys = keyof Obj;

type ObjNonHom = {
  [K in ObjKeys]: Array<Obj[K]>
}
/* type ObjNonHom = {
    a: (number | undefined)[];
    b: string[];
    c: boolean[];
} */
```

In the above code, `ObjHom` and `ObjNonHom` are similar, but `ObjHom`'s `a` property is optional and its `c` property is `readonly` (just like in `Obj`); while `ObjNonHom`'s properties are all required and mutable.

---

Being able to determine when a particular mapped type is homomorphic or not can be tricky, since there are lots of heuristics involved.  Generally speaking, a mapped type featuring `in keyof T` where `T` is some type depending on an unresolved generic parameter will be homomorphic.  Generally speaking, a mapped type featuring `in X` where `X` is some type without `keyof` directly in it will be non-homomorphic.  When a mapped type feature `in keyof T` where `T` is some non-generic type, things are iffy.  For primitives like `number` this tends to be non-homomorphic, but for object types it tends to be homomorphic.  I can probably go through GitHub and find PRs that implement each heuristic, but I don't know that it's worth anyone's time for that.

---

The particular behavior with primitives was introduced introduced in [microsoft/TypeScript#12447](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12447).  In the description, it says that:

> A mapped type of the form `{ [P in keyof T]: X }`, where `T` is some type parameter, is said to be [a homomorphic] mapped type because it produces a type with the same shape as `T`. [...] [When] a primitive type is substituted for `T` in an isomorphic mapped type, we simply produce that primitive type. For example, when `{ [P in keyof T]: X }` is instantiated with `A | undefined` for T, we produce `{ [P in keyof A]: X } | undefined`.

---

So the basic answer to the question is: when a mapped type is homomorphic and acts on a primitive type, the same primitive type comes out.  The original `DeepPartial` is homomorphic, so `number` becomes `number`.  Your modified version with `in keyof number` directly is non-homomorphic, so `number` becomes a type with each apparent property of `number` mapped to an optional property.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeAoZZOAfgC5kQBXAW3WgBoDl1yBnMKUAc0cKgjgATAPYgANgE9kCcumHCxAkHgC+ePGAkAHFAAlh1A8KhaAFsAQAeACoA+ZAF5cTANoBpZKGQBrCBOEwyNYAuuQAglBQcBI27sG2qhraKBiY+tSOyOlGJuZWqQkA9ABUyJo6aFjpmfiEhCTkABRUtNDIAD7IlCCCEDCgEIIAlC7BHV09fQOCANxMhCzI7JwgXKNzdcj8QqKS0rLyinAg66rIxYXq5SlYbn6smb7+galzSRWpAHKi1U61yO5PCBKpg7hJWKFkBEojFUnEEmoSmVkiDviBfs5NnAmi06FBxt1ev0QIMRsENnVFstuKdNjJmIclKcVOdLnggA)

Comment: excellent answer.