# How do I define a type for an object which may or may not have a property?

Tags: typescript

I recently got a runtime TypeError for something I think should be possible to catch during compile time with TypeScript. Here is the code:

```
type MyObject = Record<string, Record<string, string>>;

function getParameters(): MyObject
{
    return {
        test: {
            test: "val",
        }
    };
}

const params = getParameters();

const v = params.Section.Val; // TypeError: params.Section is undefined
```

Since `MyObject` is an object where keys are `string`s, TypeScript seems to think that any `string` can be used as a key and will result in a `Record<string, string>` value. This is usually not true, because there is usually a finite number of keys on an object unless you define a getter on the object which can return a string for any other string given as key.

So I tried to use `type MyObject = Partial<Record<string, Record<string, string>>>`. Using this type catches the above bug, but it introduces problems when you try to iterate over the object:

```
type MyObject = Partial<Record<string, Record<string, string>>>;

function getParameters(): MyObject
{
    return {
        test: {
            test: "val",
        }
    };
}

const params = getParameters();

Object.values(params).filter(v => v.Value); // v: Object is possibly undefined
```

The error above can never happen during runtime because if the property exists on `params` I know it will be a `Record<string, string>`. But I don't know how to express that using the typesystem.

So my question is: How can I define a type for an object which

- has only string keys, and
- does *not* have defined properties for *all* strings, and
- if a property is defined, I know the type of the corresponding value is `Record<string, string>`?

**Edit:** I know it is possible to specify all keys in the type (like `Record<"keya"|"keyb", string>`), but that is not what I want because I do not know all keys beforehand. What I want is a type which we can call `PartialRecord` where if `params: PartialRecord<string, T>`, then `params.SOMEKEY` has the type `T | undefined` (because the key `SOMEKEY` might not exist which means accessing it will return `undefined`) but `Object.values(params)` should have the type `T[]`, because we know `Object.values` will only return values that exist, and they are all of type `T`.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132262/typescript-deep-partial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first type of MyObject is fine, but when you try to access a property on it, you can not know beforehand if it is defined or not. In this case, you can use optional chaining.

```
const v = params?.Section?.Val;
```

If `Section` does not exist on `params`, `v`'s value will be undefined, same goes for `Val`. So make sure you check if `v` is undefined or not before using it.

If you also want to more strictly define what properties should exist, you can type an object.

```js
type MyObject = {
    test: Record<string, string>;
    [key: string]: Record<string, string> | undefined;
};
```

In this case, the property `test` is a required property of type `Record<string, string>`, and optionally any other property that is either `Record<string, string>` or undefined.

**EDIT**: Reevaluating your question and your edit, it seems like what you are looking for can be enabled with the `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` flag in `tsconfig.json`. You can read about it here https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess

Comment: The problem is that if I forget to use the optional chaining TS will just happily compile the code anyway, even though there can be runtime type errors. I want typescript to stop me if I forget the optional chaining.

Comment: In that case, consider a type like this `type MyObject = Record<string, Record<string, string> | undefined>;`.

Comment: That is what I did in my second example in the question, but it does not fulfill the third condition I want to express ("if a property is defined, I know the type of the corresponding value is Record<string, string>").

Comment: @LarsNyström I have updated the answer, it got a bit messy but for the moment I don't feel like cleaning it up. I think this may be what you want.

Comment: @LarsNyström take a look at this typescript flag https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess

Answer (score 0):

You need to list all the keys your object could have, in a way like this:

```
type MyObject = Record<"test" | "Section" | "foo", Record<string, string>>;

function getParameters(): Pick<MyObject, "test">
{
    return {
        test: {
            test: "val",
        }
    };
}

const params = getParameters();

const v = params.Section.Val; // Property 'Section' does not exist on type 'Pick<MyObject, "test">'
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys

You can also list all the keys in a separate variable:

```
type keys = "test" | "Section" | "foo";
type MyObject = Record<keys, Record<string, string>>;
```