# Cannot crop the response of TypeScript entity

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an entity that contains column users: `UserEntity[]`.

`UserEntity` has several properties such `loginName, userName, email, createdTt, updatedAt ...`
In response *[provide context]*, I have to fill "users" property only type of UserEntity. But I want to show only `loginName`, `userName`, `email`. Everything else I want to skip. How can I do it if property `users` can be only `UserEntity[]` type with all properties? Please help.

Comment: It is possible with Partial typescript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132262/typescript-deep-partial

Comment: I'm not finding it clear on if you are trying to send "less" data to an API or just "skip" display of some data returned by an API. Could you please give more context of what data you have, where it comes from or goes to, and how you want to use it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you receive an array of `UserEntity` values called `userEntities`, where `UserEntity` is defined something like this:

```
interface UserEntity {
  loginName: string;
  userName: string;
  email: string;
  createdAt: number;
  updatedAt: number;
  // etc.
}
```

If you want to create an array containing only *some* of the properties for each user, the easiest way to do so is to use `Array.prototype.map`:

```
const basicUserInfo = userEntities.map(user => ({
  loginName: user.loginName,
  userName: user.userName,
  email: user.email,
}));
```

`map` constructs a new array by calling the provided function on each element in the current array. For more info, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).