# How to do nested partials to construct "incomplete" object trees in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have this basically (a small snippet of the types I have so far, which is far from complete yet):

```
export type ASTFormType = {
  base: Array<ASTFormType>;
  hook: Record<string, ASTHookType>;
  like: "form";
  link: Record<string, ASTTakeType>;
  name: string;
  task: Record<string, ASTTaskType>;
  wear: Record<string, ASTWearType>;
};

export type ASTHookType = {
  flow: Array<ASTTaskFlowType>;
  like: "hook";
  name: string;
  take: Record<string, ASTTakeType>;
};

export type ASTTaskCallType = {
  bind: Record<string, ASTBindType>;
  like: "call";
};

export type ASTHoldType = {
  like: "hold";
};

export type ASTTakeType = {
  like: "take";
  name: string;
  takeLike: ASTLikeType;
};

export type ASTLikeType = {
  bind?: Record<string, ASTLikeType>;
  like: "like";
  name: string;
};

export type ASTTaskFlowType = ASTTaskCallType | ASTHoldType;

export type ASTBindType = {
  bond: ASTBondType;
  like: "bind";
  name: string;
};

export type ASTBondType = ASTCordType | ASTMarkType;

export type ASTCordType = {
  cord: string;
  like: "cord";
};

export type ASTMarkType = {
  like: "mark";
  mark: number;
};

export type ASTWearType = {
  like: "wear";
  link: Record<string, ASTTakeType>;
  name: string;
  task: Record<string, ASTTaskType>;
};

export type ASTTaskType = {
  like: "task";
  move: Array<ASTTaskFlowType>;
  take: Record<string, ASTTakeType>;
  task: Record<string, ASTTaskType>;
};
```

The type `ASTFormType` has a bunch of nested objects, which can have nested objects / arrays of nested objects, etc.. So you could have:

```
  const formA = {
    like: 'form',
    name: 'user',
    link: {
      email: {
        name: 'email',
        takeLike: {
          name: 'string'
        }
      },
      username: {
        name: 'username',
        takeLike: {
          name: 'string'
        }
      }
    },
    task: {
      login: { ... }
    }
  }
```

But, in this compiler, when this object is first constructed, it is hardly filled out. Instead of being filled out, it looks essentially like this (this is what I currently have):

```
export type NestedPartial<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends object ? NestedPartial<T[K]> : T[K];
};

const form: NestedPartial<ASTFormType> = {
  base: [],
  hook: {},
  like: "form",
  link: {},
  // name: "", // leave off for demo purposes
  task: {},
  // wear: {}, // leave this off for demo purposes
};
```

With that `NestedPartial`, I am trying to say "this `form` record itself is partial", meaning it doesn't have all it's properties necessarily. And also want to say, all the nested maps and arrays have objects which are also partial! So something like this (which doesn't work):

```
const form: Partial<ASTFormType> = {
  base: <Partial<ASTLikeType>>[],
  hook: <Record<string, Partial<ASTHookType>>>{},
  like: "form",
  link: <Record<string, Partial<ASTTakeType>>>{},
  task: <Record<string, Partial<ASTTaskType>>>{},
};
```

But (a), that is a lot of annotations, and (b) it doesn't actually work (syntax error).

How can I do something like this though? Partially typing the tree of objects. I don't want to say (recursively) that *everything* is `Partial` (like my `NestedPartial` tries to do (but fails at for some reason)). I want to just say that specific pieces of the tree of objects are `Partial`. How can I accomplish something like that?

That way, I can progressively build up the objects and some attributes can be undefined while I am in the middle of processing. Only later will I strip out the `Partial` from the definition, to get back to the inner object fully filled out!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: deep partial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132262/typescript-deep-partial)

Comment: Unless every piece of that hierarchy is needed for the question to demonstrate the issue, I'd strongly recommend stripping it down to something simpler, so it's actually a *minimal* [mre].