# How to make a type in TypeScript which is like a combination between Pick and Partial?

Tags: typescript

I would like to have a type where I know specific properties are going to be defined, but some properties are going to be missing. Something like this:

```
type UserType = {
  email: string
  name: {
    first: string
    last: string
  }
  address: {
    city: string
    state: string
    zip: string
    coordinates: {
      lat: number
      lng: number
    }
  }
}

const partialUser: PickPartial<
  UserType,
    | 'email'
    | Record<
      'address',
      Record<
        'coordinates',
          | 'lat'
          | 'lng'
      >
    >
>
```

Basically I am trying to select like this:

```
{
  email: string
  name?: {
    first: string
    last: string
  }
  address: {
    city?: string
    state?: string
    zip?: string
    coordinates: {
      lat: number
      lng: number
    }
  }
}
```

Is anything like this possible? I saw the [`PartialDeep`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68699273/169992) code, but that doesn't work the way I want to. I essentially want to say, these specific properties in the tree are defined (not possibly undefined), and the rest are possibly undefined `?`. How can I accomplish that in TypeScript? If not exactly, what is as close as I can get to that, or what are some workarounds?

Another API approach might be:

```
const partialUser: PickPartial<
  UserType,
  {
    email: string
    address: {
      coordinates: {
        lat: number
        lng: number
      }
    }
  }
>
```

Then everything else gets a `?` possibly undefined key. Is it possible for that to be done somehow?

Comment: Not at my PC at the moment, so hard to check anything, but here's my 2c on the second API idea. First param is `Input`, second is `Pattern`, which extends `DeepPartial<Input>`. The type is then `DeepPartial<Input> & Pattern`.

Comment: Monaco (the editor used in VS Code and the TypeScript playground) is nigh unusable on mobile.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nd2OkW) meet your needs?  I've used a different mapping object than either of your versions but hopefully it's intuitive.  If it works for you I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Please mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz yeah that is looking good! I don't fully understand it yet, perhaps you could write up an answer and explain how it works more.

Comment: I will write up a full answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd be inclined to use a structure like

```
PickPartial<
  UserType, 
  { email: 1, address: { coordinates: { lat: 1, lng: 1 } } }
>
```

where the potentially nested key set is represented by a single object, possessing the same nested keys you care about.  The nested *values* aren't really important as long as they are not themselves object types (otherwise *their* keys would be probed).  I chose `1` above because it's short, but you could use `string` or `number` or whatever.  I'm suggesting this representation because it consistently treats keys as keys and not sometimes bare string literal types.

---

Anyway, using that, we can write `PickPartial<T, K>` mostly like

```
type PickPartial<T, M> = (
  Partial<Omit<T, keyof M>> & 
  { [K in keyof T & keyof M]: 
      M[K] extends object ? PickPartial<T[K], M[K]> : T[K]
  }
);
```

First, `Partial<Omit<T, keyof M>>` means that any part of `T` that doesn't have a key in `M` (using [the `Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys)) will be made partial (using [the `Partial<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)).  Then, `{ [K in keyof T & keyof M]: M[K] extends object ? PickPartial<T[K], M[K]> : T[K] }` [maps](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) the keys of `T` which are also in `M` and either recursively `PickPartial`'s them (if the mapping value type is itself an object) or just leaves the type from `T` (if the mapping value type is not an object, such as `1` above).

This works, but produces types that are hard to inspect:

```
type Z = PickPartial<UserType, { email: 1, address: { coordinates: { lat: 1, lng: 1 } } }>
/* type Z = Partial<Omit<UserType, "email" | "address">> & {
    email: string;
    address: PickPartial<{
        city: string;
        state: string;
        zip: string;
        coordinates: {
            lat: number;
            lng: number;
        };
    }, {
        coordinates: {
            lat: 1;
            lng: 1;
        };
    }>;
} */
```

Is that the type you want?  It's hard to tell.

---

To remedy that, I will use a technique from [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218) where we take the basic type, copy it into a new type argument via [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types), and then do an identity mapping on it.  That is, if you start with

```
type Foo = SomethingUgly
```

you can get nicer results with

```
type Foo = SomethingUgly extends infer O ? {[K in keyof O]: O[K]} : never;
```

So that gives us:

```
type PickPartial<T, M> = (
    Partial<Omit<T, keyof M>> & {
        [K in keyof T & keyof M]:
        M[K] extends object ? PickPartial<T[K], M[K]> : T[K]
    }
) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
```

Now if we try it we get:

```
type Z = PickPartial<UserType, { email: 1, address: { coordinates: { lat: 1, lng: 1 } } }>
/* type Z = {
    name?: {
        first: string;
        last: string;
    };
    email: string;
    address: {
        city?: string;
        state?: string;
        zip?: string;
        coordinates: {
            lat: number;
            lng: number;
        };
    };
} */
```

Which is the type you wanted.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgFXNAvFA3gKCvqCAWwEMBLAGwC4o5hEyA7AczwMZKIhtwL6gBmZRHRp0GLNvygUSo2vSas+AXylQSAE02IIcOD3V8AxmVBjFk6fjolg3BROXWAXmTAWnRgsYD2vxE0mOz1Da35ZYBpGAFciACMkb2kKFmi4xMRkqDVVHDUcHFBIKAAFMmMAa1KSRGAyEgoAeQZmAB5kABooAFkAPihMAAoauoaKNqaiMw7uyogQXwFevoGAMmwoAG0AaSgmKHnF5eQoDaOl3oBdGh7dq8IAD3tGTTgoX3iAKwhjYCgAPzqcpVUb1RotMjtZD3bp3HZXAY0GEI-IASkKxWgAC1IcxBmUKtVauDmq02vAkKhIN0sIRSJQaABGbpaHR6AybPwBIIceycumRZndVLMZk5CUqPo4AD0ACooFioLjWgSweNJtNgBSECg0N0AETEcgUA1QAA+UANbN0+gNqzO2HUxsZjiUAG51DaOTQQcSxhDybxrKZzG6WJ7wrZ7J4Pdk3B5w8xIyH-IFgvywuECEKoLEEkgU9mZGk8xlC9kVEWcrTstz03zQk7i-hc0zq+FRcyOwQq+opZ6VFA5TLMWhCaCSRquisCUNgVPGpqZjOLst+utm9ZdvtGIcFpdTucD+ubtl4Q8IM8IK93p8fn9ARP-aSOrDevckVAUVd+zg0U8LxvLuAhIFATRPnSO4HGu4E3OB9wStEEAAG4VoURTjtiapEuqS6UnqNKbC61BQCyGjaLaApQPWvIhNRbYiqWTKSjk0oyjKUAALQ8bxfH8QJgmCQMAB63FCRJkk8aJ4nSVAImypxwAABZ6NAxgkHuiQaIwIAqUoUCLDEUAAO6af8cgyL4LAaO8KkLBouh5r4-z3r8wBwIpUAAJJQDECCaGRUCJBp-nQGYADk7xwMpATAAAdFAhTyoqWEEsG+AcFwAJZtIQgiFESY9q2ciFeIcaqNWJGxhGXqUT6W7SKGIA5UV2TRhArXlbV4QJl1ljJnWaZ0ZmjXZrm+aZMVESlpNFbhH2lX5MOo5AA)