# Can I augment an interface with properties of a const?

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to customize a [material-ui v4 `Theme`](https://v4.mui.com/customization/theming/). In a separate `@our-project/ui` package we have

```
export declare const themeOptions: {
  palette: {
    // some colors missing from Palette
  }
  status: string;
  // other properties
}
```

Following https://v4.mui.com/guides/typescript/#customization-of-theme, I should add the properties to `Theme` (and `Palette`):

```
import { Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles/createTheme';

declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createTheme' {
  interface Theme {
    status: string;
  }
  // allow configuration using `createTheme`
  interface ThemeOptions {
    status?: string;
  }
}

declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette' {
  interface Palette {
    green: PaletteColor;
    // other colors
  }

  interface PaletteOptions extends DeepPartial<AdminLightPalette> {
    green?: PaletteColor;
  }
}
```

But of course I don't want to duplicate the properties manually and have to update them when `@our-project/ui` changes. And augmenting with `interface Theme extends typeof themeOptions` doesn't compile. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

> And augmenting with `interface Theme extends typeof themeOptions` doesn't compile.

But giving a name to it does:

```
type OurThemeOptions = typeof themeOptions;
type OurPalette = typeof themeOptions.palette;

declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createTheme' {
  interface Theme extends OurThemeOptions {};
  interface ThemeOptions extends DeepPartial<OurThemeOptions> {};
}

declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette' {
  interface Palette extends OurPalette {}
  interface PaletteOptions extends DeepPartial<OurPalette> {}
}
```

where `DeepPartial` comes from [TypeScript: deep partial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61132262/typescript-deep-partial/68699273#68699273).